# How to make the colour stocked in the fill field of a svg picture a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg, colors

I'm currently working on a chat app on which people not authenticate are associated to a random fruit and a random colour.
According to these information they have an avatar which is a logo of their fruit (a svg file) coloured with their colour.

But I want to avoid to have a lot of files in my app so I just have 1 svg file for each fruit, the one in black (fill="#000000") and I'm looking for a solution to change the value of the fill field with the wright colour.

For example, if someone is a blue peach, the image peach.svg must be loaded but the "#000000" of the fill field must be erased for "#2111EF".

Do you have any idea about how I can do that? :)

I'm working with Laravel using AngularJS.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You could use [inline SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-7). Then it will be possible to apply any fill value thought CSS or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it filled with the `currentColor`.
So the parent colour would reflect on the svg.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const redButton = document.getElementById('red-btn');

redButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  container.classList.replace('blue', 'red');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 5rem;
}

div svg {
  fill: currentColor;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue" id="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M18 7l-1.41-1.41-6.34 6.34 1.41 1.41L18 7zm4.24-1.41L11.66 16.17 7.48 12l-1.41 1.41L11.66 19l12-12-1.42-1.41zM.41 13.41L6 19l1.41-1.41L1.83 12 .41 13.41z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<button id="red-btn">Red</button>
```

https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/